# OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError OT_MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED in PWA apps

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, progressive-web-apps, opentok

Have an issue with starting a session in PWA apps.

During starting video session user get an error:

```
OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError OT_MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED
```

This happens only if the user **adds the app to Home Screen.**

**Mobile systems:** iOS (Safari), Android (FF).

If the app launched like the usual website, the app works fine.

Please check an attachment.

Appreciate any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`getUserMedia` now requires a secure connection (HTTP**S**) even in Firefox.

In Firefox 68 this manifests as a `NotAllowedError`, which is how Chrome used to work until recently.

Starting with Firefox 69, the `getUserMedia` method will be entirely absent in insecure connections (HTTP), matching the spec and how Chrome works today.

`http://localhost` should still work however, since it is now considered secure.

---

From this Mozilla blog:

Firefox 68 behavior
In Firefox 68, `getUserMedia` will still be there, but the promise returned from it will always be rejected with `NotAllowedError`, while enumerateDevices will continue to work until Firefox 69. This matches how Chrome has worked for a good while (pre Chrome 74), and should be highly web compatible. It is an intermediate stepping stone to Firefox 69.

Firefox 69 behavior
In Firefox 69, both `getUserMedia` and `enumerateDevices` will throw `TypeError`. This matches how Chrome 74+ and the the spec now work.

It is worth pointing out that this `TypeError` exception will come from the absence of the `navigator.mediaDevices` object in insecure contexts—or, if callbacks are used, the absence of the deprecated `navigator.mozGetUserMedia` function. Any JavaScript that doesn’t test for this before invoking `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` will get an immediate exception thrown instead of merely having its promise rejected. Compared to Firefox 68, this might affect surrounding code, hence the two-step process.

Answer (score 0):

Safari does not support the getUsermedia API for accessing the camera when added to the homescreen. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228218/how-to-access-camera-on-ios11-home-screen-web-app/46350136). You might also find https://webrtchacks.com/guide-to-safari-webrtc/ useful.